# If the sky is full of microwave radiations then why don't we see it?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, field-theory, big-bang, spectroscopy, cosmic-microwave-background

So basically we know that the sky is full of microwave radiations but why can't we see it if so ?

Comment: Microwave radiation isn't visible to the naked eye.

Comment: @zucculent It may seem trivial but that comment shoudl probably be an answer and answers potentially earn more reputation points than comments and are also permenent, rather than comments which are not.

Comment: I down voted because it is really easy to just look up one of those ubiquitous electromagnetic spectrum figures and see the single octave range of frequencies we can see.

Answer (score 4):

[Microwave radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_radiation) spans frequencies from 300 MHz to 300 GHz. [Visible light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_light), on the other hand, spans frequencies roughly from 430 THz to 740 THz. As you can see, microwave is too far away from the visible range (several orders of magnitude) to be visible by the human eye.